# Display FontAwesome icons with JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a class that could load `FontAwesome` icons but it doesn't achieve to read the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` file.

**Class to create an icon:**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class AppFont {
    static {
        Font.loadFont(AppFont.class.getResource("/res/fontawesome-webfont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 10);
    }

    public static Label createIcon(Icon icon, int iconSize) {
        Label label = new Label(icon.toString());
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-family: FontAwesome; -fx-font-size: " + iconSize + ";");
        return label;
    }
}
```

**Icon enum:**

```
public enum Icon {

    TEST('\uf099');

    private Character c;

    private Icon(Character c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Character getCharacter() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return c.toString();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Label l = AppFont.createIcon(Icon.TEST, 40);
this.getChildren().add(l);
```

What I get

[Only the black rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2sCU.png)

and of course `.ttf` file is in the right location. It doesn't throw any error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx and http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use font awesome in a fxml project (javafx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx)

Comment: And I would like to do it without any external jars and fxml

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `-fx-font-family:` is set to the correct name for the font you are loading. I am using `Font Awesome 5 Pro Regular'` or `Font Awesome 5 Free`once you get that name right your code should work.