# Creating Glyphicons library like fontawsome for JFX

Tags: javafx

I am writing an application using JavaFX, I am using font-awesome for icons in the buttons, my challenge is that font-awesome has specific icons that I can use, but the domain for which I am creating the application will require another set, now it seems it will be a never ending journey of looking for icons.

But I do feel it will serve me in the long run if I just create my own library that I can use. I would like to know where I can find the right material on "Creating Glyphicons that can be bundled into a jar and used in a JFX Project together with scene builder during design stage"

Thanks In-advance

Kind Regards
Xavier

Comment: What icons do you need. [FontawsomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) has a very big list of icons. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx/47210978#47210978) to check out my answer on this topic.  Go to the `Currently Supported` section [here](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) and click on one of the links to see all the different icons available.

Comment: I have a Health Desktop App that I am creating, and I am pretty sure, I will get in the corner where I need specialized icons when I have deal with Drugs, Sundries, Doctors, Nurses, Pharmacists to name a few. hence I will need an expounded library of icons to make the app make sense to users

Comment: I Checked on fontawesome http://fontawesome.io/icons/  on Medical there are only 12 and I will need a wide variety of the icons to use