# FontAwesomeFX Without Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to use the [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) library in my non-Maven project. However, it seems Maven is the only way the developer has chosen to provide the latest version of the library (9.1.2).

How do I get this imported into my IntelliJ IDEA project? The 9.1.2 version is not in the Maven repositories...

I have never used Maven, so I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the jar and adding it to your classpath? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project and 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx

Comment: The author doesn't appear to release the library as a JAR, only a Maven resource. The link you provided is 5 years old and doesn't quite use the same library.

Comment: I just noticed.

Comment: @Zephyr you posted the old site for `FontAwesomeFX` since 8.10 you can find  and download the files from [Bintray: FontAwesomeFX](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/view), but when you  manually download FontAwesomeFX, you probably need to find and download all the libraries which are depended for FontAwesomeFX.