# How to upgrade FontAwesome to version 5 in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, groovy, font-awesome

I have a JavaFX using FontAwesome icons and I wanted to use the new version 5.
But it seems it doesn't work anymore.

Here's a simple demo app written in Groovy that works with the older FontAwesome version:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.text.Font
import javafx.stage.Stage

class App extends Application {
    static final String PENCIL = "\uf040"

    @Override
    void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        def root = new VBox(10)
        root.children.with {
            add new Label('My icon')
            add new Label(PENCIL).with {
                it.style = '-fx-font-family: FontAwesome;' +
                        '-fx-font-size: 24px;' +
                        '-fx-text-fill: red'
                it
            }
        }
        def scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600)
        primaryStage.with {
            it.scene = scene
            it.title = "FontAwesome Demo"
            centerOnScreen()
            show()
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        Font.loadFont( App.getResource(
                // "/fa-regular-400.ttf" /* version 5 */
                "/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" /* old version (not sure which) */
        ).toExternalForm(), 12 )
        launch(App, args)
    }
}
```

Using the old font file, it works:

[image]

After upgrading:

[image]

The docs on [upgrading to version 5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4) doesn't seem to mention anything much other than the font-family changed from `FontAwesome` to `Font Awesome 5 Free`, but changing that won't fix the problem.

NOTE: My actual app is written in Java, just using Groovy here as an example, the problem is the same though.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally got it working. Besides changing the font-family, you must use the correct font file for JavaFX, as most of the options they distribute don't seem to work...

Also, they've changed the names of the icons (nice, right?) [as shown in the upgrading docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#name-changes), so you must update them one by one.

From the web distribution, only the font files called `xx-solid-900.xx` work. The `woff` and `tiff` extensions both seem to work, but `woff2` doesn't.

I also tried the desktop distribution, which has much larger files, and only `Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf` worked.

Here's the pen icon (unicode `f303`) I found in version 5 displayed in the above app:

[image]

Sharper!!

For reference, the final source code:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.text.Font
import javafx.stage.Stage

class App extends Application {
    static final String PENCIL = "\uf303"

    @Override
    void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        def root = new VBox(10)
        root.children.with {
            add new Label('My icon')
            add new Label(PENCIL).with {
                it.style = '-fx-font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";' +
                        '-fx-font-size: 24px;' +
                        '-fx-text-fill: red'
                it
            }
        }
        def scene = new Scene(root, 100, 140)
        primaryStage.with {
            it.scene = scene
            it.title = "FontAwesome Demo"
            centerOnScreen()
            show()
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        Font.loadFont(App.getResource("/fa-solid-900.woff").toExternalForm(), 12)
        launch(App, args)
    }
}
```